# Custom Field type for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, custom-field-types

I have a scenario in which i have to create a custom field type in my sharepoint 2013 environment.

i tried going through a few examples online, i browsed thru various links and followed the content too. with those links i was able to create a field with custom field type, the field type is showing me under the "Create" tab for site columns, list columns and others as well. But when i actually create a column using that custom type it gives me an error. "error in / application...."

i searched on net for the solution but didnt got any success.

i followed this link
[Creating Custom Field Type](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/creating-a-custom-field-type-for-sharepoint-2010-email-validation-field/)

Now, i want to know that ... Is custom field type supported for all the versions of sharepoint?
and
what is the perfect way to create a custom field type, but without CSR (JsLink).

If any has any sample then please do post.

thank you.

Comment: Try changing paths '%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14' from 14 (2010) to 15 (2013).

Comment: ok thank you,

i tried creating another solutions, there was a problem with some namespace thing.